# Removing linked soft link in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, shell

currently i am wanted to clean up my proj area but the problem with rm i am facing is some copy remain in disk  
with linked i am meaning soft link

```
A linked to B 
 B linked to C
```

C which is on other directory
A & B are on same folder

know when i run

```
rm -rf A
```

it removes only A & B but the C remain on the disk how i can remove C from the disk.. using the the same command..

Comment: `rm -rf A` only removes A, not B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `realpath` like this:

```
rm $(realpath A)
```

Setting up an example:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ pwd
/tmp/tmp.QwSuHKmWwE
$ touch C
$ ln -s C B
$ ln -s B A
$ stat -c "%N" *
`A' -> `B'
`B' -> `C'
`C'
```

Showing that `realpath` does what you want:

```
$ realpath A
/tmp/tmp.QwSuHKmWwE/C
```

So running `rm $(realpath A)` is like running `rm C`.

```
$ rm $(realpath A)
$ stat -c "%N" *
`A' -> `B'
`B' -> `C'
```

Or did you want to remove all three files?

In that case, I think you'll have to write a script.

Here's something that should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -eq 0; then
    echo "Usage: dellinks.sh <file>..." 1>&2
    exit 2
fi

if ! type readlink >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "dellinks.sh: cannot find readlink program" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

for file in "$@"; do
    while test -L "$file"; do
        target="$(readlink "$file")"
        rm "$file"
        file="$target"
    done
    if test -e "$file"; then
        rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

Example:

```
$ stat -c "%N" *
`A' -> `B'
`B' -> `C'
`C'
$ ~/bin/dellinks.sh
Usage: dellinks.sh <file>...
$ ~/bin/dellinks.sh A
$ stat -c "%N" *
stat: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
rm -fr `readlink B`
```

but this will work with `B` since it will remove it's target `C`, but not with `A` because then it will only remove `B` (`A`'s target).

but that can be done easily via a script that will recursively follow links till they get a non link, then pass it to `rm -fr`

Comment: I think it's spelled "because", not "cuz" ;)

Comment: edited, cuz "because" is better ;-)